# How to run a job periodically and within certain duration

Tags: java, multithreading

Plan to run a job periodically and shut down the execution after certain duration to clean up the threads since the life time for the container is set to be 5 hours. Java `ScheduledExecutorService` provides the functionality to schedule the job periodically but the shutdown method will close the executor service immediately instead of after some duration. Is there a way to handle such case? Anyone knows if there is a better api to use in Java? Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java ScheduleExecutorService timeout task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279736/java-scheduleexecutorservice-timeout-task)

Comment: Likely you will find an answer if you Google for "schedule with timeout".

Comment: thanks. I was searching like "schedule executor service for certain duration" but with no luck..Don't know how I didn't search timeout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not schedule the Executor to shut itself down?

```
    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("tick"), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(exec::shutdown, 5, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It doesn't really matter whether the shutdown uses `FixedRate` or `FixedDelay`, since it will only run once.