# How can I interact with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) programs?

Tags: java, input, command, runtime

I'm using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) to execute some programs from the console.

If the program is finite (only accomplishes some tasks and outputs information then closes) everything is fine. I can execute the program and then my java program continues.

My problem is when the program does not finish until some user input. Then I don't know how can interact with it.

For example I have this program in java called a.jar with the following main code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = "";

   while (line.equals("q") == false) {
       line = in.readLine();
    }
```

Now if i want to run it from another java program

```
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar q.jar");
   System.out.println("Program terminated");
```

It will never show the Program terminated message. Any suggestion how can solve this problem?

I hope I have explained myself, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the below statement(waitFor method) to complete the command execution.

```
  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println("Program terminated");
```

Comment: But then p.waitFor(); will wait forever and the message won't be shown.... because the a.jar will never get the "q" input.

Comment: If you are using Java 8, you can directly use waitfor along with Timeout.

     p.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTE)

Comment: That's nice! Thanks. But it's still not what I was looking for. I would like to stop when I want.  I want somehow to input the q character so the program will terminate itself.

Comment: Other way is you can set the timeout for thread. This link might help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808276/how-to-add-a-timeout-value-when-using-javas-runtime-exec

Comment: Thanks again but I can't still not close the process. My project plays a youtube video using a media player, but I'm not able to stop it.

Comment: Here is my code: (Main class)  http://pastebin.com/Y9c7w9aK    (Excmd class)  http://pastebin.com/h72HaZXb.     I get the final message "Program should be terminated" but the video is still playing in full screen.