# Implement `Process.waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` in Java 6

Tags: processbuilder, java-6

I am working on a legacy (Java 6/7) project that uses `ProcessBuilder` to request a UUID from the machine in an OS-agnostic way. I would like to use the `Process.waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method from [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), but this isn't implemented in Java 6. Instead, I can use `waitFor()`, which blocks until completion or an error.

I would like to avoid upgrading the version of Java used to 8 if possible as this necessitates a lot of other changes (migrating code away from removed internal APIs and upgrading a production Tomcat server, for example).

How can I best implement the code for executing the process, with a timeout? I was thinking of somehow implementing a schedule that checks if the process is still running and cancelling/destroying it if it is and the timeout has been reached.

My current (Java 8) code looks like this:

```
/** USE WMIC on Windows */
private static String getSystemProductUUID() {
    String uuid = null;
    String line;

    List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>() {{
      add("WMIC.exe"); add("csproduct"); add("get"); add("UUID");
    }};

    BufferedReader br = null;
    Process p = null;
    SimpleLogger.debug("Attempting to retrieve Windows System UUID through WMIC ...");
    try {
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().directory(getExecDir());
      p = pb.command(cmd).start();

      if (!p.waitFor(TIMEOUT, SECONDS)) { // No timeout in Java 6
        throw new IOException("Timeout reached while waiting for UUID from WMIC!");
      }
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (null != line) {
          line = line.replace("\t", "").replace(" ", "");
          if (!line.isEmpty() && !line.equalsIgnoreCase("UUID")) {
            uuid = line.replace("-", "");
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
      uuid = null;
      SimpleLogger.error(
        "Failed to retrieve machine UUID from WMIC!" + SimpleLogger.getPrependedStackTrace(ex)
      );
      // ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally {
      if (null != br) {
        try {
          br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          SimpleLogger.warn(
            "Failed to close buffered reader while retrieving machine UUID!"
          );
        }
        if (null != p) {
          p.destroy();
        }
      }
    }

    return uuid;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a timeout value when using Java's Runtime.exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808276/how-to-add-a-timeout-value-when-using-javas-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code which only uses features available under Java 6:

```
public static boolean waitFor(Process p, long t, TimeUnit u) {
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    final AtomicReference<Thread> me = new AtomicReference<Thread>(Thread.currentThread());
    ScheduledFuture<?> f = ses.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Thread t = me.getAndSet(null);
            if(t != null) {
                t.interrupt();
                me.set(t);
            }
        }
    }, t, u);
    try {
        p.waitFor();
        return true;
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        f.cancel(true);
        ses.shutdown();
        // ensure that the caller doesn't get a spurious interrupt in case of bad timing
        while(!me.compareAndSet(Thread.currentThread(), null)) Thread.yield();
        Thread.interrupted();
    }
}
```

Note that unlike other solutions you can find somewhere, this will perform the `Process.waitFor()` call within the caller’s thread, which is what you would expect when looking at the application with a monitoring tool. It also helps the performance for short running sub-processes, as the caller thread will not do much more than the `Process.waitFor()`, i.e. does not need to wait for the completion of background threads. Instead, what will happen in the background thead, is the interruption of the initiating thread if the timeout elapsed.